# How form.parse() method works?

Tags: node.js, formidable

I have a doubt on how form.parse() in the below scenario works. what does it mean by fields and files from the form.parse(). I kind of not understand properly and exactly how formidable Module as well.

```
  http.createServer(function (req, res){

        if (req.url == '/fileupload'){
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req, function(err,fields,files)) // doubt on how this parsing works 
        }
        res.writeHead(200,{'content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="fileupload"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit"');
        res.write('</form>');

    }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You have some examples here : https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#example and here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128701/parse-form-value-with-formidable-to-filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the specification mentioned in github regarding form.parse.
Here form.parse is adopting the default call back function.

We can override the call function according to our requirement and then we would have access to all of our form fields and files.

Kindly refer the below mentioned link to get the detailed explanation.

Please refer : https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter "err" handles the error
The second parameter "fields" handles all the fields in a form
The third parameter "files" handles the file submitted in the form

```js
let form =  new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.keepExtensions = true;
       form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
           if(err){
               return res.status(400).json({
                   error: "Image could not upload"
               })
           }

//we are passing the form's fields that the user had submitted to a new 
//object in the line below
           const {title, body, cateogories, tag} = fields;

           let blog      = new Blog();
           blog.title    = title;
           blog.body     = body;
           blog.slug     = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
           blog.mtitle   = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
           blog.mdesc    = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
           blog.postedBy = req.user._id;


//now here we handle the file that user uploaded
           if(files.photo){
               if(files.photo.size > 10000000){
                    return res.status(400).json({error: "Image could not upload > 1MB "}) 
               }

               blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
               blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
           }
```